# What should I write in baseURL while deploying my app at heroku?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

i have problem at angular.js side in 'services.js' or say 'factory.js'.

I am not able to understand what should i write in replace of 'HERE' in baseURL when deplooying app at heroku:

```
angular.module('confusionApp')
.constant("baseURL", "__HERE__")
```

When i leave it empty, i am able to register, but not login.

I am using this when running my app locally:

```
angular.module('confusionApp')
.constant("baseURL", "http://localhost:3000/")
```

I am able to connect my database with mlab.

Everything goes well, except, when i tried to login in my app,i got error undefined in replace of $state.go().

Here is the link to my app, kindly check it yourself:

http://idiscover.herokuapp.com/

Comment: did you try `"http://idiscover.herokuapp.com/"`?

Comment: yes
then even register didn't worked.

Comment: I believe heroku forces the use of https, have you tried that?

Comment: yes i tried it at my level

Comment: ok, well one way to look at what is being sent and received is to use [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) which allows you to create a request and send it to heroku, as well as inspect what is returned back. This might help diagnose if there are any issues

Comment: okay will try...and let u know @BenDavison if it works or not. thanks for now.

Comment: @BenDavison getting 500 internal server error in postman...i replaced __HERE__ with https://idiscover.herokuapp.com/
any reason for this?
working perfectly on localhost

Comment: Well what did you try to do? have you read the response from the server? or looked at the heroku logs?

Answer (score 0):

This code worked:

```
angular.module('confusionApp')
.constant("baseURL", "")
```